# Unable to press the Reset button more than once

Tags: javascript

This is a etch-a-sketch project that I was trying to code since 2 days and I am finally wrapping up. I just need to figure out one last thing. The Reset button only works once and after that I must refresh the page in order to reset the grid and produce a new custom grid.

**HTML**

Here, I have a button for resetting the grid.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
        <title>

        </title>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="rs" >
            <button id="reset"> Reset Grid!</button>
        </div>      

        <div id="container">  </div>


               <script src="script.js">        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

Here is the CSS file. I am setting up a container and the reset button previously shown in **HTML** file to reset the grid and display

```
.active {
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg , green , yellow);
    border: none;
}

#container {
    border: gray solid 1px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(16,1fr);
   grid-template-rows: repeat(16,1fr);


}


#reset {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**JS**

Using JS to append multiple div into the parent container to fill in the grid.

default startup

```
const cont = document.getElementById('container');


for (let a=0; a < 256; a++){ 
    let him = document.createElement('div');
    him.classList.add('divi');
    him.setAttribute('style','border : solid 1px gray;')
    cont.appendChild(him);    
    him.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
        him.classList.add('active');
        him.setAttribute('style','border :none;')
    })    
}
```

To reset. Basically cleans out the grid and produces a new one with the user defined grid size. ***But Works only once, So I must refresh the page after clicking once***

```
let btn = document.getElementById('reset');


btn.onclick = reseter;

   function reseter () {
    document.getElementById('container').remove();
    let size = prompt('SIZE');
    let new_cont = document.createElement('div');
    new_cont.style.border = 'solid 1px gray';
    new_cont.style.height = '500px';
    new_cont.style.width = '500px';
    new_cont.style.marginLeft = 'auto';
    new_cont.style.marginRight = 'auto';
    new_cont.style.marginTop = '30px';
    new_cont.style.display = 'grid';
    new_cont.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size},1fr)`;
    new_cont.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${size},1fr)`;



    for (let ip = 0; ip < size*size; ip++) {
        let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.classList.add('divi');
        new_cont.appendChild(newDiv);
        newDiv.style.border = '1px solid gray';
        newDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
            newDiv.classList.add('active');
            newDiv.style.border = 'none';

        })


    }



    document.body.appendChild(new_cont);

   }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
document.getElementById('container').remove();
```

use

```
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = '';
```

What you are doing is removing the whole element, to which you have bound the event. The first time you click the reset button the element gets removed, so the second time it doesn't find the container element, and removes nothing.

What you want to be doing is emptying the container which you use to append your other divs, with `.innerHTML = '';`

Comment: This works but in addition to that it keeps generating a new grid everytime. I want it to delete all the previous grids when the user presses the reset button.

Comment: Yes, because your code removes #container, and then creates the exact same replica with let new_cont = document.createElement('div'); but that div does not have the id = container. So there are two options: 1) delete the #container and then when you create a new one, create it with the same id. 2) Don't delete the #container, empty it (as I've suggested). But then append all the grid elements into it, not into new_cont (you don't need new_cont in this case).

Comment: I hope I'm explaining it clearly. Instead of new_cont.appendChild(newDiv); use document.getElementById('container').appendChild(newDiv)

Comment: Could you tell me how could i add 10% black each time i hover over the div?

Comment: I'm glad it worked! For the hover, I think it's best if you open a new question and briefly explain what exactly you want to achieve. There are multiple ways of approaching hovering/mouseover css changes...